LM7805 output current
I have a 7805 voltage regulator, which I supply with 12 V on the input and I get 5 V on the output.
What will be the output current? I simulated this circuit, and I got 133 uA on the output which is kinda low. Should I calculate with this value to design a heat sink?


That depends fully on the load you attach. It's a voltage regulator, not a current regulator. Since you can operate a simulator, I'd expect you to be aware of Ohm's law, so it should be all kinds of obvious that the current at the output differs whether you attach a 5Ω resistor or a 5 kΩ resistor…

Seems like this would be a good time to refer you to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

I got 133 uA on the output which is kinda low. I'm a little confused why you included this information. Are you expecting something different? Also, considering the small wattage, is the preexisting heat sink not sufficient?

I want to power up NE555 with this regulator. If I understand correctly, I should look into datasheet of NE555 what input current rating it takes.

Why do you need a 5V reg. If the 555 runs on 12V?  Is this something that can be done with a 5V Schmitt Trigger?

@Simplifier Probably best to edit your question and add the info about the NE555. Even better, also add what your NE555 is doing and what its output is being connected to. If your simulator has an NE555 model you can add it to your simulation.

@SteKulov I use NE555 as a 5 V output PWM generator for a 12 V fan.

@Simplifier Edit the question to add this information. Otherwise the question will stay closed forever.

@Simplifier also please add the package size and if it surface mount how it's mounted. The more you can tell us the more we would help and more like it is that people think the question is detailed enough to be reopened. People here  are easily able to tell you all you need to know if you tell us all you know. already

The simulation you show only has a capacitor on the output. After startup, the capacitor will charge up to 5V and afterward there should be no current at all. The fact that you have 133uA points to some issue with the sim. You can ignore this. (You will get something more reasonable if you add a small resistive load to the output.)
You asked about 555 current. It's quite small: 10s of mA or less for the bipolar version, less than 0.5mA for a CMOS one. Regardless, you will not need a heatsink for the 7805 if the 555 is all you're powering with it.
But let's look at the bigger picture. Did you know that you can run the 555 on 12V directly? There's no need to make 5V for just the 555 by itself. If you have other stuff that needs 5V that's another matter.
How much current can you get from the 7805? That depends. Under the best conditions (heatsink, minimum overhead voltage) you can get 1.5A out of it. With a 12V supply and no heat sink, for the TO-220 package the max sustained current will be about 285mA (dissipating 2W).


Should I calculate with this value to design a heat sink?

You should always get in the habit of getting a rough approximation of the power dissipation of your components. It is quick, and will save you from headaches in the future.
For a LM7805, the power dissipated by current that flows through the ground pin is generally too small to worry about. So what is the current flowing through the OUT pin? Multiply that by the voltage drop between the IN and OUT pins. In this case it is 12 V - 5 V = 7 V. Now multiply that by your current.
As pointed out in another answer, in the absence of a load, you only have a capacitor, so within a short while there will be no output current. But suppose you had a load resistor. If the load draws 70 mA, the power dissipated by the 7805 would be 7 V x 70 mA or about 490 mW. Round that up to 1/2 watt, because we neglected the current through the ground.
If your 7805 comes in a TO-220 package, 1/2 watt is fine. You don't need a heat sink unless you want want. The package will get warm, but not hot enough for the regulator to auto-shut off. If you pushed the load current up to 140 mA, so that you had 1 watt dissipation, there is a chance you will, at certain points, trigger auto-shut-off. Even a small heat sink will save you from problems in this case. If you double the current again, to 280 mA and the power to 2 W, you will almost certainly hit the auto-shut-off unless you have a heat sink.
You should do a similar quick analysis for resistors, transistors, diodes etc. Every time. Or sooner or later you will find out the hard way.

Apart from irrelevant effects due to in exact simulation the output current of a voltage regulator with no load is zero.
Iout = Vout/Rload.
For a 10 ohm loadI = V/R = 5V/10 ohm = 0.1A or 100 mA.
The current drawn by a 555 circuit depends very greatly on the circuit.
It could be eg 20 mA or 100 mA or 1 A.
You need to look at your overall circuit and determine how much current will be drawn.
If the power supply is for general experimenting then designing for 100 mA max load current will be a usefu start.  Regulator dissipation = Vrop_across_reguator x I load = (12-5) x 0.1A = 0.7 watt.
Depending on what regulator package you are using a small heatsing may be useful.
My answer here tells you much about heat dissipation in regulators

I don't think the simulation is inexact. I rather assume OP connected a 5V simulation source to the output of the linear regulator.
